# Security around Workflow CPS Global Lib git repository

Tags: jenkins-workflow

What security, if any, is available for the [CPS Global Lib git repo](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/cps-global-lib/README.md#accessing-repository)? Is this fully read/writable by anyone who has added their SSH public key? Or is there a way to limit access to this repository?

Answer (score 0):

You must have the Overall/RunScripts permission in order to push to it. See also [JENKINS-26538](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26538).